# "sudo: apt-get: command not found." after removing some packages

Tags: software-installation, apt

Recently I executed this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
```

To prevent this such error message:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  openerp
```

My plan was executing these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
```

Accidentally I got this error message when trying to continue executing code:

```
[ps193731]$ sudo apt-get clean
sudo: apt-get: command not found
[ps193731]$ sudo apt-get -y install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

As additional information I'm adding this information:
Result of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`:

```
[ps193731]$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Version of libstdc++6 on system is 4.4.5-8.
dpkg: error processing apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapt-pkg4.12:
 libapt-pkg4.12 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Version of libstdc++6 on system is 4.4.5-8.
dpkg: error processing libapt-pkg4.12 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
 libapt-pkg4.12
```

Result of `apt-cache policy libstdc++6 apt libapt-pkg4.12`:

```
[ps193731]$ apt-cache policy libstdc++6 apt libapt-pkg4.12
apt-cache: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by apt-cache)
apt-cache: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)
```

Result of `dpkg -l libstdc++6 apt libapt-pkg4.12`:

```
[ps193731]$ dpkg -l libstdc++6 apt libapt-pkg4.12
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version                    Description
+++-==========================-==========================-====================================================================
iU  apt                        0.9.7.9+deb7u1             commandline package manager
iU  libapt-pkg4.12             0.9.7.9+deb7u1             package managment runtime library
ii  libstdc++6                 4.4.5-8                    The GNU Standard C++ Library v3
```

Result of `sudo dpkg -C`:

```
[ps193731]$ sudo dpkg -C
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 apt                  commandline package manager
 libapt-pkg4.12       package managment runtime library
```

Content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# Generated by ndn-autoupdate

deb http://debian.di.newdream.net/ squeeze ndn
deb http://debian.newdream.net/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.newdream.net/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://www.backports.org/debian/ squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://nightly.openerp.com/7.0/nightly/deb/ ./
```

I also have the problem installing libstdc++6 version 4.6 or above for debian squeeze. 
Because there no libstdc++6 version 4.6 or above for debian squeeze. 
How can I fix the `apt` command to be useable again?

Comment: It sounds like you have accidentally removed the `apt-get` command. Can you check and see what the status of the `apt` package is? `dpkg -l apt`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Yep, here is the result:

http://tny.cz/bba3ccd0

I'm using tinypaste, for tidier code view. ^^^

Comment: Ok. Add that to your answer. You can format it by clicking on the curly brackets symbol. That will just indent the whole thing by 5 spaces.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Ok, i have edited again my question by adding `dpkg -l apt` as additional information. Can you check it again please?

Comment: See `man dpkg-query`. The first field is `i` meaning installed, The second is`U` meaning unpacked. It should also be `i`. Try `dpkg --configure -a`, and post the output in your question. It is possible that will fix the problem, depending on what other problems your system may have.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Yep, ok, I have post output `dpkg --configure -a`. Now what I must to do next?

Comment: I see the problem. You have been mixing packages for different versions. The first question is - how badly do you want to rescue your current system? Because it will be non-trivial. Second question, you are using Debian squeeze? Please post output of `apt-cache policy libstdc++6 apt`, and also post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Also, `dpkg -l libstdc++6`.

Comment: Actually, lets make that  `apt-cache policy libstdc++6 apt  libapt-pkg4.12` and `dpkg -l libstdc++6 apt libapt-pkg4.12`.

Comment: Oh ok, I have post the output to question. 
I'm very need to rescue this system, because this is a production web server. 
Yes, I'm using Debian Squeeze on VPS.

Comment: OK, actually it might not be so hard. I should have realised `apt-cache policy` would not work. So, here is what you need to do. First, figure out which packages on your system are broken. A primitive way is to just do `dpkg -l` and then check which ones are `iU` instead of `ii`, but one can do better, I'll ask in chat.

Comment: I've asked about that here - http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114192/4671 Do you have any idea how you installed wheezy packages on a squeeze system? Also, you forgot to add `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your question.

Comment: You can remove the `dpkg -l apt` output in the earlier part of the question, since it repeated below.

Comment: Please post the output of `dpkg -C`. This should in theory list packages that have only been partially installed on your system.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I only have 19 reputation, so not yet enough to chat, sorry. 
No, I do not even understand what you are asking about installing wheezy packages on a squeeze system. 
I have done what you told. 
For next need I to execute `dpkg --configure apt libapt-pkg4.12`?

Comment: You have `apt` and `libapt-pkg4.12` packages which belong to wheezy, Debian release 7, but they are installed on squeeze, Debian 6. I was asking if you knew how this happened. In any case, the good news is that your system does not look too badly broken. You should be able to fix it by (1) downloading `apt` and `libapt-pkg4.12` Debian squeeze binary packages for your arch, and installing them using `dpkg -i apt...deb libapt-pkg4.12...deb`. I'll elaborate in an answer below. Since apt is not working, you'll need to use something else. Do you have a functioning web browser?

Comment: Also, do you have wget installed and working?

Comment: The line `deb http://nightly.openerp.com/7.0/nightly/deb/ ./` in your sources.list looks dubious. Comment it out for now, with a `#`. You can always restore it later.

Answer (score 5):

```
apt-get -s remove debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt apt-show-versions debian-archive-keyring debian-keyring debtags
  python-software-properties python3-software-properties
  software-properties-common tasksel tasksel-data unattended-upgrades
  upgrade-system
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt debian-archive-keyring (due to apt)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 12 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

So, what you did... you literally removed apt and ignored the warning, then hell broke loose. Never ever, remove stuff without checking and double checking what is being done.

So, to summarize:

If you use 32-bits:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.10.3+squeeze1_i386.deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.4/libstdc++6_4.4.5-8_i386.deb
```

if you use 64-bits:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.10.3+squeeze1_amd64.deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.4/libstdc++6_4.4.5-8_amd64.deb
```

Download the keyring:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-archive-keyring/debian-archive-keyring_2012.4_all.deb
```

Now remove and install

```
sudo dpkg -P libapt-pkg4.12 apt
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_4.4.5-8_*.deb apt_0.8.10.3+squeeze1*.deb debian-archive-keyring_2012.4_all.deb
```

Check everything is ok:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get check
```

Now this should be a life lesson. Don't mess with something shall not be messed with.

This answer is equally valid to any Debian-based distribution, just change Debian's hostname for your distribution's, ie:

- Ubuntu: `http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/`
- Mint: `http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/`

And the correct path, ie.:

```
http://host/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.4/libstdc++6_4.4.5-8_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the comments, the problem is that the poster somehow installed package for Wheezy on Squeeze, namely `apt` and `libapt-pkg4.12`. The poster verified that those were the only packages misconfigured, by doing

```
[ps193731]$ sudo dpkg -C
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 apt                  commandline package manager
 libapt-pkg4.12       package managment runtime library
```

Therefore, the obvious remedy is to manually download (since apt is currently broken) a Squeeze `apt` packages for the poster's arch, and install it using `dpkg -i`. `libapt-pkg4.12` doesn't exist for queeze, so should be removed.

The poster hasn't specified his arch, but assuming `amd64` this link should work:

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.10.3+squeeze1_amd64.deb

If it is `i386`, substitute that for `amd64`. So

STEP 1:

```
dpkg -P libapt-pkg4.12
```

STEP 2:

```
wget -c http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.10.3+squeeze1_amd64.deb
```

STEP 3:

```
dpkg -i apt_0.8.10.3+squeeze1_amd64.deb
```

NOTE: It is possible that just STEP 1 + running a `dpkg --configure -a` will suffice to install `apt`, but it will still be the wrong apt for squeeze, so the preceding steps are preferable.

EDIT: @Braiam points out that dpkg will not remove `libapt-pkg4.12` if there is anything depending on it. But you have the wheezy apt depending on it. So you may need to do

```
dpkg -P --force libapt-pkg4.12
```

Alternatively, as @Braiam suggests, one can do

```
dpkg -P libapt-pkg4.12 apt
```

The latter version is probably preferable, since using a `--force` flag is best avoided except when absolutely necessary.

Comment: He needs to remove `apt` along `libapt` or dpkg will not follow due dependency issues with apt. Check with `dpkg --no-act -P libapt-pkg4.12`

Answer (score 0):

Download the `apt` package(s) to a local directory and install them directly with `dpkg --install`.

(or try `aptitude` if it's installed)

Note: the answer to the unasked question... openerp isn't signed, so you're always going to see that warning.

Comment: It always have required dependencies when I want to install `apt_0.9.7.9+deb7u1_amd64.deb`,
Cause when I install `libapt-pkg4.12`, I got this problem: `libapt-pkg4.12 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6)`.
And my big problem is there no libstdc++6 version 4.6 or above for debian squeeze.

Comment: As others have said below, that's the wrong apt... version 0.8.10.3+squeeze1 is the current release for squeeze.

Comment: And its possible to get rid of that warning by editing sources.list and setting it to trusted. Or at least so says the documentation.